# Trend chart with error bars uding GGplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data, which is summarised by the group and quarter. I want to plot three different trend charts for each of the groups, with error bars. The data is already summarised and I want the values plotted, as they are. I am fairly new to ggplot2 and am struggling to calculate the error bars around the value for the plot. can anyone please help?

```
Group     Quarter    Proportion
1          1         1.03
1          2         4.02
2          1         2.02
2          2         6.01
3          1         2.01
3          2         8.09
```

Comment: I was reading through this link http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/ but the sd/ci calculations suggested on the summarySE functions, do not work with my data-presumably because my data is already grouped?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to calculate error bars from this data. You only have one value for every point, so how can you calculate error? You should use the data before summarizing.

Comment: Wont I be able to calculate CIs around the values for the error bars?

Comment: You can calculate CI from some statistical model fit - you'll need the full data for that.

Comment: Do you know the standard error for these values that you could use to calculate a CI?